# Is it possible to delete cookies after the same period of time while refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I want to make the cookie deletion code work after the same period of time with updating the page, in order to delete the cookies and update the page with it

**Auto refresh manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Auto Page Refresh",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Automatically refresh a webpage every 5 seconds.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "commands": {
    "toggle": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+R",
        "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+R"
      },
      "description": "Toggle Auto Refresh"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

**popup.js**

```
let refreshIntervalId = null;

function toggleAutoRefresh() {
  const startStopButton = document.getElementById("startStopButton");
  const refreshIntervalInput = document.getElementById("refreshInterval");

  if (refreshIntervalId) {
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    refreshIntervalId = null;
    startStopButton.textContent = "Start";
  } else {
    const intervalValue = parseInt(refreshIntervalInput.value);
    if (intervalValue <= 0 || isNaN(intervalValue)) {
      alert("Please enter a valid refresh interval (seconds).");
      return;
    }

    startStopButton.textContent = "Stop";
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        const currentTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.reload(currentTab.id);
      });
    }, intervalValue * 1000); // Convert to milliseconds
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("startStopButton").addEventListener("click", toggleAutoRefresh);
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Auto Page Refresh</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Auto Page Refresh</h2>
  <input type="number" id="refreshInterval" placeholder="Enter refresh interval (seconds)" />
  <button id="startStopButton">Start</button>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Cookie Remover manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CookieRemover",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "remove cookies of current page",
  "author": "tricora",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "images/icon128.png",
      "default_title": "Remove Cookies of current page"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "cookies",
      "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.cookies.getAll({
    url: tab.url
  }, function(cookies) {
    var url = new URL(tab.url);
    var domain = url.hostname;

    cookies.forEach(function(cookie) {
      chrome.cookies.remove({
        url: url.origin,
        name: cookie.name
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Make the cookie deletion code work after the same period of time while refreshing the page, in order to delete the cookies and update the page with it

Comment: you really want that in a separate extension - why the different manifest version? does chrome even allow manifest version 2 any more?